# Can't change WooCommerce cart total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_calculate_total', 10, 1 ); 
    function woocommerce_calculate_total( $cart ) {
    if($cart->subtotal < 300){
        $cart->subtotal += 85;
        $cart->total += 85;
    }
}
```

This piece of code seems to work fine but only for subtotals. `$cart->total` always returns 0 no matter what and its lower than subtotal. I've also tried `$cart->cart_contents_total`, it returns proper value but i cant change it.
WP version is 5.3.2 and WC is 3.8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 30 );
function woocommerce_after_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
if($cart->subtotal < 300){
        $cart->subtotal += 85;
        $cart->total += 85;
    }
}
```

Comment: That one works just fine. Thank you! Do you know by chance if there's any way to also change total of cart of WooCommerce Menu Cart plugin in the menu?